# Displaying a popup when component unmounts

Tags: reactjs

I have this functional component rendered on a page. If a user clicks outside of the page on another
link I want to be able to show a popup(Displaywarning)

In the useEffect return unmount I did setDisplayWarning(true)

This is not working. Do you guys have any idea on how I can show the popup?

```
        const MyBanner = () => {
          const theme = useTheme()
          const classes = useStyles(theme)
          const { toggleUserView, impersonateUser } = usePermission()
          const [timer, setTimer] = useState<NodeJS.Timeout | null>()
          const [displayWarning, setDisplayWarning] = useState(false)

          useEffect(() => {
            return () => {
              if (impersonateUser) {
                setDisplayWarning(true)
              }
            }
            // eslint-disable-next-line
          }, [])

          const toggleUser = () => {
            const tmr = setTimeout(() => {
              toggleUserView()
            }, 3000)
            setTimer(tmr)
          }

          const clearTimer = () => {
            if (timer) {
              clearInterval(timer)
              setTimer(null)
            }
          }

          if (!impersonateUser) {
            return null
          }

          const onDialogClose = () => {
            setDisplayWarning(false)
            toggleUserView()
          }

          return (
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <div className={classes.messageWrap}>
                <FaInfoCircle className={classes.icon}></FaInfoCircle>
                <p className={classes.messageText}>You are viewing as the client</p>
                <Button onClick={toggleUser} className={classes.buttonStyle}>
                  Switch back to Zombie user
                </Button>
                <p className={classes.messageText}>
                  {timer && (
                    <>
                      Refreshing...
                      <Button onClick={clearTimer} className={classes.buttonStyle}>
                        Cancel
                      </Button>
                    </>
                  )}
                </p>
              </div>
              {displayWarning && (
                <WarningDialog
                  info={`Leaving my View`}
                  onClickPrimary={onDialogClose}
                  onClose={onDialogClose}
                  title='Leaving View'
                />
              )}
            </div>
          )
        }

        export default MyBanner
```

Comment: Have you checked if condition `if (impersonateUser) {` passes?

Comment: impersonateUser comes back to be true

Comment: I tried to put an alert statement after if(impersonateUser) and the alert is getting hit and displays the message I passed.

Comment: maybe `WarningDialog` needs some props to be visible? For example `open`. Anyway, you need to make sure that `WarningDialog` is rendered in react components tree. [React Dev Tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html) is really usefull here.